# How do I change my Technic Launcher playername for offline LAN play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking, minecraft-technic-pack

I want to know if you can change the playername used to join servers, so me and my friend can both play a modpack for Technic Launcher using the same account. Is this possible? and if it is, How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible (to my knowledge) to legally be on the same account online (even though you are playing LAN, it still authenticates with the online server)

As such what you are asking is not possible. However, there exist patched tecnic launchers out there who do not require a password to play and that would enable you to play on a LAN, but a LAN only, or servers who allow those kind of accounts.

Unfortunatly I don't think I can link you to that.